# How to get the winning team?

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, api

I've got Match and MatchStat.

```
Match(id: integer, team_a: integer, team_b: integer)

MatchStat(id: integer, match_id: integer, team_id: integer, points: integer)
```

for example i need to get all of winning match of team_id = 1

```
match 1 = (team_a: 1, team_b:2)
match_stat 1 = (match_id: 1, team_id: 1, points: 45)
match_stat 2 = (match_id: 1, team_id: 2, points: 67)

match 2 = (team_a: 1, team_b:2)
match_stat 3 = (match_id: 2, team_id: 1, points: 54)
match_stat 4 = (match_id: 2, team_id: 2, points: 43)
```

Comment: Or should I restructure my models?

Comment: `match 1 = (team_a: 1, team_b:2)` is not valid code. I understand what you're trying to say, but please try to provide valid code, not pseudocode, when possible. It would have been trivial for you to write this using `Match` and `MatchStat` - so that the code is actually valid ruby.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Untested, but you should be able to find it with something like:

```
Match.find(1).match_stats.group(:match_id).select('MAX(points)')
```

I don't see why you should use a separate model in this case. Are you planning on running matches where there are more than 2 participants? Otherwise I'd just store the score and the winnner in the Match model.

Comment: Your query is for the first match only im aiming for all matches. I've done that already i've registered the winning_team and winner_score. And yes i only got 2 participant per match. Should i return it to that model again?

Comment: I see no reason to store the stats in separate records. That creates difficulties as you always have to use GROUP queries to find the winner (like in my example). I'd add three attributes: score_team_a, score_team_b & winner_id. That allows you to set-up a double relationship between Team & Match, one to find all the matches they participated and another one to find matches they won.

Comment: Thank you for your suggestion. I guess i should revert it back. Including loser_id.

Comment: That would be redundant... you could create a negation query that gets the loser. If participant but not winner, you are the loser. But for convenience, you could do this.

Comment: Shouldn't that be `group(:team_id)`, not `group(:match_id)`?

Comment: I've reverted my model again now i got this. I'm having problem on getting the Average points of the winner.
Match(id: integer, team_a: integer, team_b: integer, score_team_a: integer, score_team_b: integer, winner_id: integer)

example. 
match 1: (team_a: 1, team_b: 2, score_team_a: 46, score_team_b: 65, winner_id: 2)
match 2: (team_a: 1, team_b: 2, score_team_a: 87, score_team_b: 54, winner_id: 1)

I'm having trouble because i don't know what points should i get?

Comment: Just create a method in the Match model, that returns the highest of score_team_a and score_team_b: `def winning_score [score_team_a, score_team_b].max end;`

Answer (score 0):

Based on the limited information you have provided, I don't see any need for the `MatchStat` model; it only complicates matters. I would scrap it, and just store the score inside the `matches` table:

```
Match(
  id: integer,
  team_a: integer,
  team_b: integer,
  team_a_points: integer,
  team_b_points: integer
)
```

To get all winning games for `team_id = 1`, you could then do:

```
Match.where(team_a: 1).where('team_a_points > team_b_points').or(
  Match.where(team_b: 1).where('team_b_points > team_a_points'))
```

This could potentially be a little simpler if you add some logic to always ensure that `team_a_points >= team_b_points`; but that's up to you.

Comment: That's actually my problem now i can't find what point should i get? Yes i got the winner but how can i know between those two points? I like your idea about the logic. But I'm saving the match first as score_a = 0 score_b = 0 then update.

Comment: @something I don't understand, sorry. What do you mean by *"Yes i got the winner but how can i know between those two points?"*? Can you explain in more detail? Are you asking about *ongoing* matches? (In which case, something like a `status` column would be useful.)

Comment: You asked for "all winning matches for a team", and that's exactly what my solution provides. In some matches, they are `team_a`; in other matches, they are `team_b`. But either way, they are the winning team.

Comment: First, I restructured my Model to this Match(id: integer, team_a: integer, team_b: integer, score_team_a: integer, score_team_b: integer, winner_id: integer). I can easily get the winner and now i need to get the Average Point for Winning team. Now i can't get the point because i got two points score_team_a and score_team_b how can i know what point between those two should i get? for example. team_id = 1 is the winner and they're on team_a so i need score_team_a how can i know that score_team_a is the one that should i get not the score_team_b?

Comment: i'll follow your advise "This could potentially be a little simpler if you add some logic to always ensure that team_a_points >= team_b_points; but that's up to you." thank you!

Comment: why not use winner_points and loser_points. Or do you not yet know the winner when creating the record?

Comment: @something There is no need for a `winner_id`. (Besides, if the match is a draw then there's no winner!!) You'd also be duplicating information.